# Can I Have The Same Effects As pthread_setcanceltype With Asynchronous Cancel From Outer Threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, kill

Can you call pthread_setcanceltype with Asynchronous Cancel option from other threads than the current thread (or is there any other alternative functions to that), so to force kill a thread from another thread, if the current thread has Defered Cancel option activated instead?

In addition, is there anyway to know if the thread is cancellable or not, as calling pthread_cancel on a thread with infinite loop will return the same value as a successful cancel, which is 0?